# CMake cross-compile: If my library depends on thirldparty, what shall I do?

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I program a library on windows by visual studio uses CMake. It depends on the thirdparty named "aTest". The CMakeLists.txt is simple such like this:

```
add_library(
        test
        SHARED
        "test.h"
        "test.cpp"
)
include_directories(${aTestIncludePath})
target_link_libraries(
        test
        PUBLIC ${aTestPath}
        )
```

It works well, it generate a libarary called a.dll and a.lib on Windows. And then, I push my code into my ubuntu system.
of course it works well too, generate a library named liba.so on Ubuntu.
Then I want to build my library for Android platform, I use cmake command like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${ANDROID_NDK}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI="armeabi-v7a" -DANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_NDK -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-22 ..
```

**Then I found a problem:
I must specify DANDROID_ABI to tell CMake which architecture I want, such as x86,armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a etc.** So the most confused point is coming:

My libaray is depened on thirdparty named aTest, Does this means that If I want to build my library for Android architecture x86, armeabi-v7a I must also compile the thirdparty by source code for Android architecture x86, armeabi-v7a? generate the difference architecture thirdparty library and invoke it, run above command again?

**It doesn't look scientific at all!
If thirdparty depends on other thirdparty, it would be trouble!
for example liA.so depends on liB.so, liB.so depends on libC.so
I must compile Android architecture x86, armeabi-v7a version libC.so and then uses it to compile liB.so, finally the liC.so.**

**Is there a way that I just compile one time and get my target architecture library?**

Comment: You should compile your third-party code with the same toolchain as your own code. How else would compiler know that you want `libB.so` for `armeabi-v7a` and not `x86`? You may ease your life a bit if you adapt some package manager like `vcpkg`.

Comment: @Osyotr thanks a lot! In fact I am a Newbie about CMake and C++,  and I dont know there is something call vcpkg! So I naturelly think that perhaps there is a way needn't to compile thirdparty one by one, and just need compile self project for different architecture .